# How can I adjust the order in which sprockets loads scss files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, assets, sprockets, asset-pipeline

I would like to influence the order in which my scss files are put into the final application.css file, because I would like to be able to overwrite some styles that have been defined in another scss file.

I have no idea how to do this.

Kind regards,

Nils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like.

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require file1
 *= require file2
 *= require file3
 */
```

Comment: Yeah, thx, it seems to work to require those explicitly in the desired order.